# An object within an iframe has a src that is an svg file, type image/svg+xml. It renders as text on remote server, but as image on local server. Why?

Tags: apache, svg

I have a web page that contains an *iframe*, and within the *iframe* is an *object* with a *src=* attribute of an svg file that displays properly when I serve the page from localhost (running apache 2.4 on Windows 10). But when I serve the same page from an Amazon Linux instance, also running apache 2.4, the svg file for the object is rendered as text. I'm quite sure the pages are the same, because the content of the *htdocs* tree is managed by git, and I make changes on the Windows 10 PC and commit them, then push and pull them onto the Amazon Linux machine.

I've attached two screenshots of what I see in Chrome Developer Tools for the same page on the two systems. As you can see, on the PC, the <*object*> expands into a *#document* followed by an <*svg*>. But on Linux, the <*object*> expands into a *#document* followed by <*html*>, with the source code of the svg file wrapped in a <*pre*> tag within the <*body*>. How is this even possible?? I'm using the same Chrome bowser instance, the only difference is which server is serving the page. [image: Server running on PC] [image: Server running on Amazon Linux]

Comment: check the mime-type returned by the two systems

Comment: Most likely the Amazon server is not configured to deliver SVG. SVG _can_ contain scripts; some hosting parties block SVG for that reason. Like Robert says, you can tell from the mime-type. Check the files in the Network Tab in F12 DevTools

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Yes indeed! Although I didn't actually use the Network tab, since there were so many files loaded by the request. Instead, I dug around and found the mime.types file used by apache (actually I'm using xampp, so it was in /opt/lampp/etc). The file was very old (from 2002), and had no entry for .svg files. So I replaced it with the contents of http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/branches/2.2.x/docs/conf/mime.types?view=markup, restarted apache, and that fixed the problem.  If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RobertLongson Also a good idea, but it didn't lead me directly to checking the mime.types file used by apache the way that Danny's comment did. Updating it and restarting apache fixed the problem. But oddly enough, neither the apache config on the Windows 10 PC, nor the config on a different Amazon Linux server (the one we use for development and testing)  had an entry for svg in their mime.types files, but they served the page correctly. Things like this make me marvel that developers can get their web sites working at all! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I offered [Danny '365CSI' Engelman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2520800/danny-365csi-engelman) the opportunity to post his comment as an answer, but he didn't take it, so I'll post the answer myself. My problem was that the Apache server I was using had a rather old `mime.types` file in the etc directory of its configuration (I was using xampp, which has its own etc directory packaged with it). That old version of `mime.types` did not have an entry for `.svg` files. Replacing it with a newer version from svn.apache.org, and restarting the server, solved the problem.

I found this quite surprising, since my `<object>` element had an attribute of `type=image/svg+xml`, which is the same as the type given in the updated `mime.types` file. Surprising because the `file` command on the server recognized the file as having that mime type. And so the lack of an entry for `.svg` in the `mime.types` file actually caused apache to ignore the type attribute on the object element, and render the content of the object as text!